# Swift assigning multiple classes to UI element

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

Is it possible to assign multiple custom classes to the same UI Element in Swift?

I have a UITextField that I need to animate with Spring(Animation library) and I also need to use some other library on the same UITextField that provides some other functionality. I usually assign the custom class in the identity inspector custom class section in the storyboard but I can't find a way to assign multiple classes. I also tried to create a new class and inherit from both of these libraries that I am trying to use but I don't think you can have multiple inheritances in Swift.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, Swift does not support multiple-inheritance. An object can implement multiple protocols but only [inherit](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Inheritance.html) from one class.

Answer (score 1):

For sorry this is not available in Swift ( Great **C++** has it ) , so you have to select anyone and go with it

Comment: Ugh, that is bad... Each of the libraries was intended for completely different purposes and I needed the functionality of both.

Comment: Yes , very bad faced same issue before , swift is updated continuously hope they make this possible some day

Comment: @Sh_Khan They won't. Multiple-class inheritance was a good intention going very bad and there is a reason why it was not implemented in any modern programming language. The same problem multiple-class inheritance was trying to solve was solved in Java using interfaces and in Swift using protocols.

Comment: @Sulthan the popular problem is **Diamond Problem** which can be solved if the developer is aware of what he's doing , Besides good popular libraries have different prefixing in their content something like XYZ before each class/method name , so it's the coder problem but they decided to remove it completely

Comment: @Sh_Khan Oh yes, it can be solved if you know the internal implementation of both classes and it makes the whole language very fragile. The solution is to have multiple inheritance for *interfaces* (protocols), not for classes. It's not something we want to have in any language and there is a reason why this "feature" have been shunned in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I just came up with a great idea that fits my needs perfectly but it might not apply to everyone. Since one of the libraries I was trying to use was purely for animation, I placed my UITextView inside a view, inherited the animation library for the view and inherited the other library for UITextView. Now I have both the animations working and the functionality.