# Using custom uiview xib

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xib

I'm trying to use custom views from xib files, but I don't know how to set the placeholder view in the storyboard equal to one of the xibs. Also, I can't just set the placeholder uiview's property to one of the xibs because I need to be able to switch between different xibs. This is what I have so far.

```swift
import UIKit  
class Viewcontroller: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var placeholderView: UIView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        placeholderView = view
    }
    
    class func instanceFromNib() -> CustomView {
            let view = UINib(nibName: "CustomView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! CustomView
            return view
    }
```

[image: storyboard picture]

Comment: What is the thing you call the place holder view?

Comment: The placeholder view is just an empty uiview

Comment: It would be helpful if you show your storyboard with it.

Comment: Ok, I added a screenshot

Comment: Your screenshot doesn't show where the thing that you call the place holder view is located and how it is connected to your storyboard.

Comment: The blank selected thing is the place holder view, it takes up the whole view controller

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom class for your Xib view where you load the nib as follows:

```swift
class MyCustomView: UIView{
override init(frame: CGRect) {
      super.init(frame: frame)
      commonInit()
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
      super.init(coder: aDecoder)
      commonInit()
  }
  
  private func commonInit(){
      Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomView", owner: self, options: nil)
     
  }
}
```

You can add all of the outlets and stuff you need there.

The view in your storyboard must be of the type of your Xib view. Change it both in your code and in your storyboard:

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var placeholderView: MyCustomView!
```

From storyboard:

1. Click the view
2. Go to the identity inspector
3. In the class thing write `MyCustomView`

Comment: I already have a class for my xib and I don't want to change the class of the storyboard view identity inspector because I need to be able to use different xibs, not just one

Comment: Well, use more views and hide them when they're not needed, then. As far as I know you can't assign multiple classes to an object: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50727692/swift-assigning-multiple-classes-to-ui-element

Answer (score 0):

Instead of thinking in terms of a "placeholder" view that will be replaced by some other view, think about it as a "container" view... you would add the xib's view as a subview, just as you would add any other subview.

So, when you want to show the view from a xib, you would:

- remove the current subview from the container (if one is already there)
- load the view from the desired xib
- add it as a subview to the container
- set constraints relative to the container